# Creating a "database" in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a rails 4 application where users define for example a `tools` database and creates fields that store items like brand, year, etc. Then a CRUD interface is presented before them, based on the fields they defined.

Right now I have a Database model that looks like this:

```
class Database < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :fields
```

and a Field Model that looks like this:

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :database
```

Basically, right now on the Add Fields page (which is after you have a created a database and defined the fields), I'm creating a unique id and storing that with all the fields on that page, which I then use to group fields into a "row" (using a rails groupby statement).

I have two questions: 
1. Is the most efficient way to implement a "database"?
2. I can't figure out how to best link the field names you define when you create the database with the fields in the CRUD interface. So for example, If I create a `name` field when I'm initially defining all of the fields, how can I have it associated with fields in the CRUD interface?

Thanks for all help! If I need to clarify more, please tell!

Comment: in Database model: `accept_nested_attributes_for :fields` and use `fields_for :field` in the Database's form to create a field related to your Database object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Postgres with the HStore extension as ActiveRecord 4 supports hstore out of the box now.

Using a meta-data design for storing attribute values is not very efficient performance wise, and updates are kind of slow once rails does all of its model validation checks so I would avoid it for storing user data.

You will still need some kind of schema table for tracking the users attributes/fields that they define including their type, a display name, required/optional etc so that your application can properly validate the input and have enough information to build a view.

But Postgres hstore does work well and is intended for working with user defined data. Postgres also supports indexing and querying on hstore columns too so its not slow.

Your design will need a `schemas` table and a `rows` table.

The `schemas` table will have columns for the user it belongs to, the field name, display name, type, range etc.

The `rows` table will have columns for the user it belongs to, and a values hstore column for holding all of the values the user has defined in their schema.

For details and how-to's there are quite a few simple guides just google "hstore ActiveRecord 4" as the official documentation doesn't seem to have caught up yet.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know your business model but I don't know if making a whole new db is what your after. 
This looks like a need for a key/value store. postgres has a hstore.

I would use a postgres hstore on your database table where each row represents a database and the hstore contains a lists of key/values representing each arbitrary field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not meaning to create an actual database, I mean create an application that acts as a "database" for the user where the user can enter names and types of fields, and then is presented a CRUD interface to insert/update/delete based off the fields he/she had defined originally. Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: Well in that case you are basically creating a key/value for each "database"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear what the end goal is, but you could have your Field model with name, type, value, and user, which is the relationship to a User model. Clearly, 1 user has many fields.

So let's say user Bob created fields "Product Name" and "Product Price." His UI would have text boxes for "Product Name" and "Product Price." The price box might have a dropdown saying "less, greater, equal" associated with it because you know the type is numerical. So your query would basically say in pseudoSQL "Select all fields for user Bob where the name is "Product Name" and the value is (or like) the name given in the Product Name textbox AND the name is "Product Price" and the value is (<|=|>) the value given in the Product Price text box (after parsing into a number).

Maybe.

If all else fails, consider writing the code as you want it to look. It can be very helpful to go from the code to the database structure rather than the typical other way around.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason i can not attach the class diagram of DB objects but try to get that idiea from below table structure it self.

From the End user’s perspective, s/he will be looking at the list of field name on UI. And then pull some of them on some unique place on UI to indicate those are together. 
That will form a new DB. We another way I look at it is that is nothing but the table.
I worked on the project where we tried to achieve dynamically generate CRUD through C# code by reading the Table Definition.
If you look at the below diagram, this may clear out some doubt. Basically we need to store some metadata table and code can use that build CRUD out of that.
below are the sample DB objects you can start with. depending on how complex and sophisticated Design you want you can add more functionalities to it.

```
    DECLARE @_DBField TABLE
    (
        ID      INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
        ,NAME   sysname NOT NULL
    )
    DECLARE @_FieldDataTypeID TABLE
    (
        DataTypeID      INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
        ,SqlDataType    sysname NOT NULL
        ,DisplayName    sysname NOT NULL
    )
    DECLARE @_DB TABLE
    (
        ID          INT NOT NULL
        ,DBName     sysname NOT NULL
        ,FieldID    INT NOT NULL
        ,DataTypeID INT NOT NULL
        ,IsPartofPK BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    )

    INSERT INTO @_DBField( NAME )   
    SELECT 'FName' 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'LName' 
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'MName'

    INSERT INTO @_FieldDataTypeID( SqlDataType ,DisplayName)
                SELECT 'NVARCHAR(50)'       ,'Short-String; Alphanumeric value'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'NVARCHAR(200)'      ,'Midium-String; Alphanumeric value'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'NVARCHAR(500)'      ,'Long-String; Alphanumeric value'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'      ,'Max-String; Alphanumeric value'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'INT'                ,'Small-Integer; Integer Value'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'BIT'                ,'0 or 1; Boolean Value'


    INSERT INTO @_DB( ID ,DBName ,FieldID ,DataTypeID ,IsPartofPK )
                SELECT 1,'Student_Name',1,1,1
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'Student_Name',2,1,1
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'Student_Name',3,1,0

    SELECT * FROM @_DB
```